# socket.io client not firing events on socket io server

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have built a backend and wanted to test it with some front-end code but for whatever reason, it is just not firing the events on the server. I dont get the "on connect" event triggered. I already downgrade the backend to a version similar to my testing script but still all the server shows, are logs like this.

[22/Oct/2021:14:06:21 +0000] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NoeKlFT&b64=1 HTTP/1.1" 404 149 "-" "node-XMLHttpRequest"

I am using socket io for server and client version 3.1.2

Here is the backend code snippet

```js
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
const morgan = require("morgan");
const cors = require("cors");
const config = require("./src/config/general");

const exchangeController = new ExchangeController(io); // I want to pass in the IO obejct to be able to deal with all the event stuff in another file besides the apps entry point file.
```

Here is the part where I want the IO object to be available and work with the events from there

```js
class ExchangeController {
  constructor(io) {
    this.io = io;
    this.exchangeService = new ExchangeService();
    this.router = express.Router();
    this.initRoutes();

    this.io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      console.log("incoming socket connection"); //gets never logged to console when connecting frontend
       //do further stuff (deleted for post)
      });
    });
  }
```

This is the frontend script for testing the connection

```js
//client.js
const io = require('socket.io-client');

const socket = io("mysecreturl") //also tried localhost instead of deployed app url no difference
// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connect', function (socket) {
    console.log('Connected!');
  
});
```

I really tried for way too long now without getting any results. I hope you guys can guide me on the right path again.

Cheers

Comment: Did you start the server?

Comment: lol yes otherwise I would not receive the mentioned logs on the server I posted right in the beginning of my question.dude

Comment: Nobody any ides?